# Limit computation issue

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Consider the following function:
\begin{equation}
Y_t = A_t \left[\delta K^{\frac{\sigma -1}{\sigma}}_t + (1-\delta)L^{\frac{\sigma -1}{\sigma}}_t \right]^{\frac{\sigma}{\sigma -1}}
\end{equation}
where $\sigma$ and $\delta$ are two constants, and $\sigma \in [0, \infty]$ and $\delta \in (0,1)$.

Now, I want to find the limit for $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial K}$ when $K \to \infty$ for three different cases: $i) \sigma <1$ , $ii) \sigma =1$ and $iii) \sigma >1$.

I start by computing the partial derivative:
\begin{equation}
A_t \left[\delta K^{\frac{\sigma -1}{\sigma}}_t + (1-\delta)L^{\frac{\sigma -1}{\sigma}}_t \right]^{\frac{1}{\sigma -1}} \delta K^{-1/\sigma}_t
\end{equation}

Then, in case $i)$:
I focus on:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{K \to \infty} \left[\delta K^{\frac{\sigma -1}{\sigma}}_t  \right]^{\frac{1}{\sigma -1}} =0
\end{equation}
because the exponent $\frac{\sigma -1}{\sigma} <0$. E.g., for $\sigma=0.5$, the exponent is $-1$ and $\lim_{K \to \infty} \frac{1}{K_t} =0$.

Similarly,
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{K \to \infty} \delta K^{-1/\sigma}_t =0
\end{equation}
Thus, the limit for $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial K}$ when $K \to \infty$ when $\sigma <1 $ is zero.

In case $ii)$, trivially, the limit is zero.

However, in case $iii)$, the book says that the limit when $K \to \infty$ for $\sigma >1 $  reads $A_t \delta^{\frac{\sigma}{\sigma -1}}$. Can you show me why?

Comment: Note that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial Y}{\partial K} = A\left[ \delta  + (1-\delta) \left(\frac{L}{K}\right)^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}} \right]^{\frac{1}{\sigma-1}} \cdot \delta$. Now take the limit in the regime $\sigma > 1$ to obtain your answer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot